# Change theorem numbering in R Markdown HTML to remove section number

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

Is there anyway to change the theorem numbering in R Markdown using Bookdown's HTML output to

Theorem 1

Theorem 2

etc.

instead of the default, which includes the section number like this

Theorem 1.1

Theorem 1.2

Comment: Add an example of your output. Chunk of the code and an image.

Comment: Are you using section numbers for anything else? If not, add `number_sections: FALSE` as an output option in the YAML. If you are looking for a more specific and want great answers quickly, make your question reproducible. For example, what exact output is in your YAML? (There are many options that render in HTML.) Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.